# pandas dataframe of arrays to matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe containing arrays into a matrix and are searching for the best way to do it.
Lets say I have this dataframe and I would like to slice out two rows that should result in a matrix of size 2x2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]})
df['a'] = df['a'].map(np.array)
```

The following attemts generates a numpy array of objects resulting in an array of size 2:

```
df.loc[0:1,'a'].to_numpy().shape   # (2,)
df.loc[0:1,'a'].values.shape       # (2,)
np.array(df.loc[0:1,'a'].values).shape   # (2,)
np.array(df.loc[0:1,'a']).shape    # (2,)
```

This is the closest solution I've found, but it's adding an extra dimension and I do not understand why this works but not the ones above.

```
np.array([df.loc[0:1,'a']]).shape  #( 1,2,2)
```

Does a solution exists to directly convert it to shape [2, 2] without looping or removing extra dimensions?

Comment: np.array([df.loc[0:1,'a']])

Compare to your above attempts, why you have added **[]** inside **array()** function, and why not in other attempts?

Comment: I tried different things and by adding [] it seems to work. but this adds an extra dimension which I don't want. that's why I don't have more examples of that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert value to nested lists and then to `array`:

```
a = np.array(df.loc[0:1,'a'].tolist())
print (a)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]

print (a.shape)
(2, 2)
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],'b':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] })
print (df2)
        a       b
0  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]  [3, 4]
2  [5, 6]  [5, 6]

b = np.array(df2.loc[0:1,'a':'b'].values.tolist())
print (b)
[[[1 2]
  [1 2]]

 [[3 4]
  [3 4]]]

print (b.shape)
(2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: I still get shape (2,) from you example above

Comment: @Dangraf - It is interesting, I got `(2,2)`

Comment: @jezrael I wanted to know more about your intuition behind using `tolist()` rather than `np.reshape`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat - OK, if think it is bad solution, be free explain it.

Comment: @jezrael hey,you have the best solution by far,I just wanted know how you come up with this.I mean no disrespect,just like to learn

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat - No, we dont understand each other. I think here working my solution, if is beter or not, no idea. So ask you about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to generate a (2,2) array you want. I have also added a df2 with two columns, which could be reshaped into a 2x2x2 array per your comments. But my solution feels like a hack. I am sure it could be improved.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]})
df['a'] = df['a'].map(np.array)
np.concatenate(df.loc[0:1,'a'],axis = 0).reshape(2,-1).shape

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],'b':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] })
np.array(df2.loc[0:1,'a':'b'].applymap(np.array)
         .apply(np.concatenate, axis = 0)).reshape(2,2,-1).shape
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, but maybe my example was too simplified. when adding eg two columns and two rows you should get a matrix of size 2x2x2 and then this solution does not seem to work any more..

Comment: @Dangraf could you provide an example for this

Comment: ```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]})
df['a'] = df['a'].map(np.array)
df['b'] = df['a]

cols = ['a','b']
df.loc[0:1,['a','b']].to_numpy() #(2,2), expected (2x2x2)
np.array([df.loc[0:1, cols]]).shape  #( 1,2)
```

Comment: I modified my code to change the df2 with two columns select to a 2x2x2 array. You could use it as a guide to get what you really want. It might be hard to get a completely general purpose solution that works for any n-d array.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little modification to the answer posted by @jezrael
I hope this will work for you.

Suppose your data frame is this

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],'b':[[11,2], [6,9], [5,6]]})`

do this for both columns

`a = np.array(df.loc[0:1,'a'].tolist())
b = np.array(df.loc[0:1,'b'].tolist())`

and then you concatenate the two array

`np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1).reshape(-1,2,2).shape`